# Cant get rid of 'nan' from my list. Please suggest solutions what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, nan

Following is the code where I want to get all the non nan values into a separate files but its not working! I tried blank, I tried isnan, or just 'nan' but I still get a list with the nans in them.

[image: I want to get rid of these nans]

```
import numpy as np
ponum1 = [i for i in ponum1 if str(1)!= np.isnan]
```

I also want to get rid of that decimal .0 and convert it to a string! Please help

Comment: `ponum = [str(int(i)) for i in ponum1 if i is not np.nan]`

Comment: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer. This the error i get when i run your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension:-

```
ponum1=[str(int(float(i))) for i in ponum1 if i is not np.nan]
```